# ionic http get request return status 0 in device

Tags: angularjs, http, mobile, ionic-framework

i tried to get dynamic data from a external url using get method in http, it works fine in browser but when i run it from device the get request is not processed and returns status 0. CORS is also enabled. the controller is added below for reference

```
$scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get("http://somedomain")
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.firstname = data;

            })
            .error(function(data, status,headers,config) {

      $scope.data = data;
      $scope.status = status;
      $scope.headers = headers;
      $scope.config = config;
            });
    };
```

Comment: Access origin in config.xml or $http caching.
You can white-list every domain with:   <access origin="*"/>

Comment: its already like that but still same error

Comment: You can check your request with Chrome Dev Tools. You just need to use inspect devices option (url chrome://inspect/#devices) and then you can see requests in Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not related to CORS, but after upgrade to Cordova 5 I needed to add the cordova plugin whitelist in order to keep backend requests working properly:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/update-to-cordova-5-0-0-make-http-call-error/22703